# IBQuery1: Cannot perform this operation on an open dataset.

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, база-данных, firebird

Написал приложение, которое подключается к базе данных и должно отображать данные таблиц (пока что одной). На DataModule накидал IBQuery (select * from clients), IBDataSource, IBDataSet, IBDataSetProvider связал их с IBDatabase, находящееся на другой форме. При открытии окна с DBGrid (связанным по DataSource c IBDataSource) возникает ошибка

```
IBQuery1: Cannot perform this operation on an open dataset.
```

Отладка показала, что эта ошибка возникает на строке

```
mydm.IBQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

в следующем блоке кода

```
procedure TfmTableData.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var openTable : TTableSpec;
    CountColumns : integer;
  I: Integer;
begin
  openTable:=TTableSpec(DBSchema.Tables.FindComponent(fmListOfTables.Listbox1.Items.Strings[fmListOfTables.Listbox1.ItemIndex]));
  CountColumns:=openTable.Fields.ComponentCount;
  //DBGrid1.Columns.:=CountColumns;
  {for I := 0 to CountColumns-1 do
      begin
        DBGrid1.Columns.Add;
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].Title.Caption:=openTable.Fields.Components[i].Name;
      end; }
  MainWindow.IBDatabase1.Connected:=true;
  //IBTable1.TableName:='CLIENTS';
  mydm.IBDataSet1.Close;
  mydm.IBQuery1.Open;
  mydm.IBQuery1.ExecSQL;
  //IBDataSet1.Open;
  //IBTable1.
  //fmTableData.DataSource1.DataSet:=IBDataset1;
  //fmTableData.DBGrid1.DataSource:=fmTableData.IBDataset1;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что вы вызываете метод Open, а потом сразу заним еще и ExecSQL.

```
mydm.IBQuery1.Open;
mydm.IBQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

Надо выбрать что-то одно. Для SELECT запросов используйте метод Open. Для всех остальных, которые не возвращают набор данных, используйте ExecSQL. 
У вас в данном примере, лишний метод ExecSQL, т.к. запрос у вас типа SELECT в Query.

Answer (score 0):

`Open` лишний, достаточно только `ExecSQL`

Comment: @savro нет open не лишний, так как без него возникает сообщение

    use Open for a Select Statement.
(это показывате также отладка на  операторе`mydm.IBQuery1.ExecSQL`). Причина не в Open. Удалите этот ответ - он не правильный.

Comment: примечание: частая ошибка начинающих - для запросов, не возвращающих данные, вызывать метод Open вместо ExecQuery (ExecSQL, ExecProc). Метод Open используется для выполнения запросов select. IBSQL.ExecQuery (или IBQuery.ExecSQL) используется для запросов insert, update, delete, и execute procedure.

http://www.ibase.ru/devinfo/sp_call.htm